# C# certificate for desktop program

Tags: c#, certificate

I do not know what steps I have to take in order to be able to create a desktop C # program using Visual Studio in the .NET Framework, which will not show the inscription during installation that it will come from an untrusted source.

Of course I tried to sign it with my own key, but it has no right to work for anyone other than my machine. I found a lot of articles on this subject, but most of them concern the ways that a corporation can do (setting up a server, using company-certified certificates, root certificate, certificate for SSL etc.). Microsoft's documentation does not in any way lead to how to create a certificate for an independent project. If I understand correctly, I have to buy a certificate somewhere in order to be able to use it to sign my application.

What steps should I take to prevent my program from prompting?
Is there any free form of certification?
Where to get the certificate?

The question may not be well-worded for this page, but in a way it's about programming, and after a week of looking for a working scheme, I don't know what to do and I don't know where to look for help.

Comment: You probably need to buy a domain and buy a certificate against that domain that allows code signing. It's highly unlikely that you'll be able to find one of these for free, unlike simple HTTPS certificates like letsencrypt. Notice also that this might not be cheap (likely in the hundreds USD per year range)

Answer (score 0):

What you're interested in is a code signing certificate. There are a number of providers but I use [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/). Once you have the certificate, it's easy to sign your application (you can also sign your installer) by doing something like:

```
signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /n <SubjectName> Application.exe
```

You will receive your `SubjectName` with your certificate.

Comment: Thank you. Is this like: https://www.ksoftware.net/code-signing-certificates/ ? it's much cheaper 84$ vs 499$, so I'm wonder if it is that same software.

What difference in practice is between OV and EV?

Comment: If you're an independent developer I think the cheaper option could be good for you, that's what I would try if it were me. The more expensive options have greater reputation for one. For example certain antivirus software will think it less likely that your app is malware if signed with an EV cert from a high-end certificate authority (CA). I believe EV certs can only be issued to companies (not independent devs) and also have a hardware token instead of just a cert file. EV is what my company uses, I have a USB hardware token for signing apps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that I ask next question if I buy certificate, and have problem with using it.